# can't populate dropdown box dynamically using IE11

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to populate a dropdown box in HTML using javascript and it works fine in Google Chrome but when i tried it on IE11 it does not work

Below is my code:

```
document.getElementById("startTime").value = myVariable;
```

Anyone has any idea how do i make it work in IE11?

Comment: Give us more context. This one line of code is not enough. Anything in the console?

Comment: Okay i think i might have found out the problem. I am trying to populate time into my dropdown, for e.g. "08:30 am". It has a length of 8 including the white space in between. however, when i do a .length for myVariable, it has a length of 13 even though its the exact same string. any idea why ?

Comment: I will repeat what @HynekS said. Please. Share. Some. Code.  
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

I try to make a test with IE 11 using code below.

```html
<!doctype html>
<head>
<script>
function SelectElement(id, valueToSelect)
{    
    var element = document.getElementById(id);
    element.value = valueToSelect;
    alert("string length= " + valueToSelect.length);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" onclick="SelectElement('startTime', '08:30 am')" value="set value"/>
<select id="startTime" name="startTime">
  <option value="07:30 am">07:30 am</option>
  <option value="08:30 am">08:30 am</option>
  <option value="09:30 am">09:30 am</option>
  <option value="10:30 am">10:30 am</option>
  <option value="11:30 am">11:30 am</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Output:

[image]

You can see that code is working fine on my side and string length is also 8 characters.

You can try to make a test with this code example on your side and check whether it is working or not.

If issue persist then try to provide your full sample code and also try to post your output. We will try to check it and try to provide you further suggestions to solve the issue.